# How I print the input character?

Tags: arrays, c, string, character

Hey I am beginner in programming i need help to solve this problem
I want that i input some character and i want to print it..

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 char a[50];
 printf("Enter character...");
 scanf("%s",&a[50]);
 printf("You entered is %s",a[50]);
 return 0;
}
```

From the above code I am not getting any output i also try using loop but not get any result please help me what is correct program so that if i enter any string i print on the screen?

Comment: change `&a[50]` to simply `a` in the `scanf` line and the `printf` line.

Comment: It would be beneficial to go through a basic C book or tutorial before proceeding further.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&a[50]);` --> `if (fgets(a, sizeof a, stdin)) { printf("You entered is %s",a); }`

Answer (score 0):

So here's your issue.

You are defining an array of type `char` with a length of 50. You then read from stdin a string, and then store it at the address of the 50th element. So what will happen is you are storing the string "out of bounds" and you may get a crash, or may not.

Either way, something very bad is happening. You are writing data to an area of memory that you should not be.

So what you want to do is write that data to the address of the 0th index of the array.

You do that by using `&a[0]` or, for simplicity's sake: `a`. Both mean the same thing.

At the end of the day, what you want is this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 char a[50];
 printf("Enter character...");
 scanf("%s",a);
 printf("You entered is %s",a);
 return 0;
}
```

I understand you are a beginner and are learning basic concepts, but keep in mind, this code is *very* unsafe. Because if someone types in a length of characters longer than 50, you are back in the same boat you were before.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting **kaylum**'s comment, *"It would be beneficial to go through a basic C book or tutorial before proceeding further."*

Now about your issue, change these lines:

```
scanf("%s",&a[50]);
printf("You entered is %s",a[50]);
```

to

```
scanf("%50s", a);
printf("You entered \"%s\".\n", a);
```

If you just want to print what's inputted by the user then you could use *buffer*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  char c;
  printf("Enter the string(~ to exit)\n");
  while((c = getchar()) != '~')
   putchar(c);
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter the string(~ to exit)
This is a test program // press enter
This is a test program // same output
~ // exit
```